# Weird error in NCC / TS-NODE prevents building TypeScript project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ts-node

I'm trying to transpile and bundle my typescript project using NCC and getting a weird error which I don't seem to understand nor find any reference on google. I'm running NCC like this from command line:

❯ **yarn run ncc build ./test.ts -o build/**

Nota: The content of "test.ts" is just: console.log('Hello!');

And getting the following output:

```
ncc: Version 0.26.2
ncc: Compiling file index.js
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@vercel/ncc/dist/ncc/loaders/ts-loader.js):
Error: Could not load TypeScript compiler with NPM package name `/home/edu/repos/some-project/node_modules/@vercel/ncc/dist/ncc/typescript.js`. Are you sure it is correctly installed?
    at Object.loader (/home/edu/repos/some-project/node_modules/@vercel/ncc/dist/ncc/loaders/ts-loader.js.cache.js:1:352078)
    at /home/edu/repos/some-project/node_modules/@vercel/ncc/dist/ncc/index.js.cache.js:1:3258300
    at /home/edu/repos/some-project/node_modules/@vercel/ncc/dist/ncc/index.js.cache.js:1:2210953
    at eval (eval at create (/home/edu/repos/some-project/node_modules/@vercel/ncc/dist/ncc/index.js.cache.js:1:1140143), <anonymous>:11:1)
```

TypeScript and NCC are both is installed locally. I already tryed with global installations of both and it's the same.

If I try to do the same using **ts-node**, I also get an error:

❯ **yarn run ts-node test.ts**

```
yarn run v1.22.0
$ /home/edu/repos/WB-DataCollectorService/node_modules/.bin/ts-node test.ts
/home/edu/repos/WB-DataCollectorService/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:7943
        An_index_signature_parameter_type_cannot_be_a_union_type_Consider_using_a_mapped_o
                                                                                          

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at loadCompiler (/home/edu/repos/some-project/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:186:20)
    at create (/home/edu/repos/some-project/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:190:28)
    at Object.register (/home/edu/repos/some-project/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js:162:21)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "some-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@vercel/ncc": "^0.26.2",
    "async-mqtt": "^2.6.1",
    "chalk": "^4.1.0",
    "graphql-request": "^3.4.0",
    "is-ip": "^3.1.0",
    "lowdb": "^1.0.0",
    "mem": "^8.0.0",
    "moleculer": "^0.14.11",
    "mqtt": "^4.2.6",
    "nats": "^1.4.12",
    "node-opcua": "^2.28.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "ts-node": "8.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lowdb": "^1.0.9",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.16"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "debug": "node --inspect -r ts-node/register src/index.ts"
  }
}
```

I have tryed many different versions of typescript and ncc, and also many other changes in the package.json but it's always the same.

Same with my tsconfig.json, none of the changes made a differente, this is the current tsconfig.json anyway:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build",
    "target": "ES2019",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "es2017",
      "es2018",
      "es2019"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

I'm running node version 12.19.0.

I'm running out of ideas and don't know where else to look at, other projects (at least eight) work perfectly using TypeScript, NCC, ts-node, etc... same tsconfig.json file and build command...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: We would probably need to see the file itself. It says unexpected end of input, could be a simple syntax error...  I would say anyway it's an installation error of some sort. The first error points to that.